# What is the name of the problem where you should isolate a branch, but can only "cut" at select locations.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:**

I have a connected network as in the picture linked below. The network has nodes (a, b, ...), branches (1, 2, ....) and a select few places to "cut" ($\alpha, \beta , ...$). The goal is to find the minimum amount of places to "cut" when a branch should be isolated.

For example, say if branch 6 should be isolated then the solution would be to cut at:
$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \mu $

[image]

**Question:**

I want to learn how to solve this problem for a general network so that I can program the solution. But I don't know what this problem is formally called so I am struggling to find literature on the subject. Does anyone know what this problem is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *min cut*, see for example Wikipedia's [Minimum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut). In the traditional minimum cut, you can cut any edge, but for your case you can consider the weighted variant, where you give cuttable edges weight 1 and uncuttable edges some very large weight.

These problems are solved with max flow algorithms, see for example Wikipedia's [Max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).